# ios - Xcode 10: Razorpay pod "module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, razorpay

Earlier I was using Xcode 9.3 but yesterday I updated it to Xcode 10 and its giving me compiler error:

> error: module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler: /Users/viraj/Desktop/Vachan app/vachan-ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

things which I have tried to resolve it

- pod update.
- deleting all pods and reinstalling them.
- deleting derived data.
- In Xcode 10, I have the project setting, Swift Language 
  Version, set to Swift 4.Here is the image 
  [image]
- clean ,build and relaunching xcode.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this? Am I missing something? Xcode bug?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use pod with swift version 4.1 just write post install script in your Podfile or update to pod version which suppots swift 4.2.

```
# Post install script

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'razorpay-pod'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried updating my pod file to latest version but getting same issue.

Comment: Do you use pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.0.24'? 
For version 1.0.24 (Framework Compiled in Swift version 4.2, Use it if you are using Xcode version 10 and above).

Comment: Try to clear CocoaPods cache, re-download and re-install all pods:

**`rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update`**

Comment: I am using razorpay-pod version '1.0.22' actually